# Android передача данных полученных через Jsoup в AsyncTask'е в конструктор для заполнения RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, jsoup, android-asynctask

Получаю с URL заголовок сайта в String переменную через Jsoup в AsyncTask'е. Далее нужно, передать эту переменную в конструктор для заполнения RecyclerView. Но я не знаю, что написать в метод onPostExecute. 
P.S. Работает, если сделать класс JsoupAsyncTask не private, а public, но я не знаю доставит ли мне это проблем или нет?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String TAG  = "mLog";

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.imageView)
ImageView imageView;

private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
ListItem item;
String URL = "https://sinoptik.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0";
Document document;
String head = "something";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
    jsoupAsyncTask.execute();


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    listItems = new ArrayList<>();


    item = new ListItem(
            head,
            "desc1"
    );
    listItems.add(item);

    adapter = new MyRecViewAdapter(listItems, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private class JsoupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            head = document.title();
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    }
}

}
```

Адатпер MyRecViewAdapter.java:

```
public class MyRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public MyRecViewAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    //return our view
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.tvHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
    holder.tvDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvHead;
    public TextView tvDesc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_head);
        tvDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
    }
}
}
```

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem {

private String head;
private String desc;

public ListItem(String head, String desc) {
    this.head = head;
    this.desc = desc;
}


public String getHead() {
    return head;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}


}
```